# How can i stop further execution of express middleware

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, express, middleware

I want to get this functionality if(thereIsSomeError) //stop executing further. for example if there some error accurs in middleware or  in the callback then i don't want to execute callback(in the app.route) and the middleware further
I tried this code. But i'm still getting `req.err` as true. how can i fix this issue

```
// My MiddleWare
export let Middleware=()=> {
return (req,res,next)=>{
    next()
    console.log(req.err) // Problem is here.. i'm still getting req.err(true)
    if(!req.err){
        db.query(`query`,(error, responseData)=>{
            if(error) console.log(error)
            db.query(`second query`,{...// send data to the 
database})
        })
        }
    }
}



//End point    
app.post('/addStudent',Middleware, (req, res) => {
//setting error to true initially
    req.err=true;
    let data = req.body
    db.query(`query `, data.username, (err, d) => {
        if (err) return res.json(err)
        else {
        // since no Error accured so set the error to false
        req.err=false;
            let q = 'query';
            let values = {//data here}

            db.query(q, values, (err, data) => {
                if (err) return res.status(200).json(err)
                else return res.status(200).json({ data })
            })
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: `if (thereIsSomeError) return next()`

Comment: But Sir.. iif there is some error i don't wan't to execute the actuall callback and middleware further ...

Comment: Hi the reason you get still get the  req.err true is because you define it after running middleware.

Comment: No.! 
Look at the code again. I called `next()` first & then i'm printing `id`. I think `db.query()` is async process, that's why i'm getting this error. any solution or alternative method ?

Answer (score 0):

First, a middleware runs BEFORE a request, NOT AFTER. If you set `req.err = true` in your POST endpoint, IT WILL STAY TRUE, meaning your database call will certainly return an error.

Second, to successfully abort a middleware call, use `return`. Returning a function stops it immediately. You can choose either to return `next(err)` to forward the error to the handler, or to use `return res.send('Error')` to terminate the response in the middleware.